# Drop all table with name like TABLE_REPO_%_<SYSDATE-2>, TABLE_REPO_%_<SYSDATE-3>, TABLE_REPO_%_<SYSDATE-4> and so on.

Tags: sql, oracle

As a part of my script i create tables to take backup of data everyday and create tables with name sysdate -1. But i dont want to load my DB with such tables so i am dropping those tables also once they are 2 days old. This helps me to keep the data for 1 day. The table names will be like:
    TABLE_REPO_CR_SYSDATE-1
    TABLE_REPO_DRP_SYSDATE-1
    TABLE_REPO_UPD_SYSDATE-1

so suppose today is Mar 28th and i run my script the backup tables will be created as:

```
TABLE_REPO_CR_20170327
TABLE_REPO_DRP_20170327
TABLE_REPO_UPD_20170327
```

And tomorrow (Mar 29th) when i run job the tables from today and tomorrow will be:
    TABLE_REPO_CR_20170328
    TABLE_REPO_DRP_20170328
    TABLE_REPO_UPD_20170328
On 30th Mar when i run script there will be:
    TABLE_REPO_CR_20170329
    TABLE_REPO_DRP_20170329
    TABLE_REPO_UPD_20170329

Now my question is i want to delete all tables which have name like TABLE_REPO_%_(SYSDATE-2 and less) eg all tables other than TABLE_REPO_%_(sysdate-1)

Individual i can delete as under, but how to delete all??

```
 BEGIN

  FOR t in (SELECT tname FROM tab  WHERE tname like 'TABLE_REPO_%' || to_char(sysdate-2,'yyyymmdd'))
  LOOP
    EXECUTE immediate 'drop table ' || t.tname;
  END LOOP;
  EXCEPTION  WHEN OTHERS THEN
        IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
             RAISE;
        END IF;
  END;
  /
 COMMIT;
```

Thanks!

Comment: sysdate, EXECUTE immediate  ----- I think you are using Oracle

Comment: What's wrong with the way you posted? Looping through the tables and executing the DROP should work, Why do you need a different solution?

Comment: Maybe you mean how to do to do -2, -3, -4 etc. in one go - which you could do with another loop; or more simply change your cursor query to exclude tha dates you want to preserve. But isn't that a one-off clean-up - if you run this every day you will only have one day's worth to remove normally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just change your cursor query to find all matching tables *except* those for today or yesterday:

```
FOR t in (
  SELECT table_name as tname FROM user_tables
  WHERE table_name like 'TABLE_REPO_%'
  AND table_name NOT like 'TABLE_REPO_%' || to_char(sysdate-1,'yyyymmdd')
  AND table_name NOT like 'TABLE_REPO_%' || to_char(sysdate,'yyyymmdd')
)
LOOP
```

If your mail tables also start with `TABLE_REPO_` you could either exclude those explicitly as well:

```
  AND table_name NOT IN ('TABLE_REPO_CR', ...)
```

or look for any that end with eight numeric digits (which is an assumption that will always be a date...):

```
  WHERE regexp_like(table_name, '^TABLE_REPO_.*\d{8}$')
```

(I've also switch to look for `user_tables.table_name` instead of `tab.tname`, as that is more commonly used. In the docs it says "TAB is included for compatibility. Oracle recommends that you do not use this view.")

Quick demo to show what would be found (and dropped):

```
with user_tables (table_name) as (
  select 'TABLE_REPO_CR' from dual
  union all select 'TABLE_REPO_CR_' || to_char(sysdate - 3, 'yyyymmdd') from dual
  union all select 'TABLE_REPO_CR_' || to_char(sysdate - 2, 'yyyymmdd') from dual
  union all select 'TABLE_REPO_CR_' || to_char(sysdate - 1, 'yyyymmdd') from dual
  union all select 'TABLE_REPO_CR_' || to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmdd') from dual
)
SELECT table_name as tname FROM user_tables
WHERE regexp_like(table_name, '^TABLE_REPO_.*\d{8}$')
AND table_name NOT like 'TABLE_REPO_%' || to_char(sysdate-1,'yyyymmdd')
AND table_name NOT like 'TABLE_REPO_%' || to_char(sysdate,'yyyymmdd');

TNAME                 
----------------------
TABLE_REPO_CR_20170326
TABLE_REPO_CR_20170327
```

Incidentally, you may also want to check that tables for today and/or yesterday **do** exist, in case there has been a problem or a delay or whatever that could leave you with no backups.

Comment: This looks okay but this will drop my main tables too as they have name like TABLE_REPO_CR,.TABLE_REPO_UPD etc. I want to retain them and delete all tables older than 2 days.

Comment: @Mishti - yes, if they match that pattern; sorry,  I hadn't picked that up from the question. I've added two options to exclude them. (Shows the importance of vetting and testing code from the internet rather than blindly running it... well done *8-)

Comment: Thank you so muchhhhhhhhh :) This works fine for me!!